# Give an example, with proof, of a function differentiable at a point, whose derivative is non-differentiable that point.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This question was labeled as either prove or disprove. I think that this is impossible, here is my reasoning:

Any function $f(x)$ with asymptotic behavior at some point $x=a$ will hold this asymptotic behavior in the function $F(x)=\int f(x) \, dx$. We have not yet covered any technical terms with integration, only differentiation.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider the function

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

at $x = 0$.

Comment: More precisely, something like $x^3 \sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$, and $0$ if $x=0$, right? That function is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: Might as well take $x^2\sin(1/x)$ also

Comment: @DavidLui Thanks for the feedback. You're right. I've made that change.

Comment: @ElliotG I see that saulspatz has used your suggestion in an answer. I realize now I was considering something else, so your idea is valid. As such, I've deleted my previous $2$ comments. Also, thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: It's a still a worthwhile example because you can modify it to get 1) $f$ not continuous, 2) $f$ continuous but not differentiable, 3) $f$ differentiable but $f'$ not continuous, 4) $f$ differentiable and $f'$ continuous but not differentiable, or 5) $f$ and $f'$ both differentiable.

Answer (score 9):

The absolute value function is continuous so has an antiderivative. The antiderivative is differentiable at 0, but its derivative (the absolute value function) is not.

Answer (score 8):

One of the simplest is $f(x) = \begin{cases} \phantom{+}x^2 & \text{if } x\ge0, \\ -x^2 & \text{if } x<0. \end{cases}$

The derivative is $f'(x) = \begin{cases} \phantom{-} 2x & \text{if } x>0, \\ -2x & \text{if } x<0, \\ \text{what?} & \text{if } x=0. \end{cases}$

At $x=0$ one can compute $\displaystyle f'(x)= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)} h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\pm h^2 - 0} h =0.$

Comment: The derivative can also be rewritten more recognisably as $f'(x) = 2|x|$.  The fact that this isn’t differentiable at 0 is then a commonly given early example of non-differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x)=\cases{x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right),&$x\neq0$\\0,&$x=0$}$$

We have $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=0$$

For $x\neq0$, we have $$
f'(x)=2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$$
which is not continuous at $x=0$, let alone differentiable.

Comment: isn’t $\lim_{x\to0} x\sin(1/x)=1$

Comment: @drfrankie No, you're thinking of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.  We have $x\to0$ and $|\sin(1/x)|\leq1$

Comment: ah yes that’s what I was thinking of

Answer (score 0):

A general class of examples *for our time* is *splines*. Let $f(x)$ be a cubic spline with a knot at $x_0$. Then $f$ is continuous with a derivative at $x_0$, its derivative $f'$ likewise, but $f''$ is not differentiable at $x_0$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)